# Curious pattern matching syntax in

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, lift

An example from [lift cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000030/ch04.html#_solution_34), the pattern matching is bit curious here.

```
serve("issues" / "by-state" prefix {
    case "open" :: Nil XmlGet _ => <p>None open</p>
    case "closed" :: Nil XmlGet _ => <p>None closed</p>
    case "closed" :: Nil XmlDelete _ => <p>All deleted</p>
  })
```

I don't understand what the `XmlGet _ part` is doing.
Could anyone explain a bit?

Comment: it's some kind of partial function. I would suggest got to RuleHelper class and looks for hidden implicits there.

Comment: answered in the gitter room. It's the same syntax as `_ :: Nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of Scala's nice niche features is that many binary operations (e. g. `f(x, y)`) can be invoked from the infix position `x f y`.  This applies to normal method calls:

```
case class InfixMethodCalls(x: Int) {
  def wild(y: Int): Int = x + y
}

val infix = InfixMethodCalls(3)
infix wild 4
```

type constructors:

```
// A simple union type based on http://www.scalactic.org/
trait Or[A, B]
case class Good[A, B](value: A) extends Or[A, B]
case class Bad[A, B](value: B) extends Or[A, B]

def myMethod(x: Int Or String): Int

// This is the same as
def myMethod(x: Or[Int, String]): Int
```

and `unapply` / `unapplySeq`:

```
object InfixMagic {
  def unapply(x: Any) = Option((List(x), x))
}

123 match {
  case v :: Nil InfixMagic x => println(s"got v: $v and x: $x")
}

// is the same as

123 match {
  case InfixMagic(v :: Nil, x) => println(s"got v: $v and x: $x")
}
```

So in the case [of `XmlGet`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/d3c52c5f9172d84fe16c6e82202f0f4e881bd848/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/rest/RestHelper.scala#L149-L177) this syntax here:

```
case "open" :: Nil XmlGet _ =>
```

is the same as:

```
case XmlGet("open" :: Nil, _) =>
```

And the `_` is ignoring the `Req` parameter, which is the second part of the returned value from `TestGet.unapply`.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through `RuleHelper` class of `liftweb` framework one will be able to make few assumptions.

1. `XmlGet` and `XmlDelete` extends `TestGet` trait with unapply method and Request argument. So this part basically means: check if it's `XmlGet\XmlDelete` method with any request.
2. How list is separated from second part? Good question. Suppose `implicit` `listStringToSuper and listServeMagic` used for this purpose.

https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/rest/RestHelper.scala